# Jquery extract from url

Tags: jquery

I have a string like this "/blog/post1/"

how can i get the "post1" from this string in Jquery ?

I tried this but it returned empty.

```
var post_slug = $(this)[0].pathname.substring($(this)[0].pathname.lastIndexOf("/")).replace(/^\//, "");
```

Comment: [`split`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format is **always** the same you can use:

```
var str = "/blog/post1/";
var piece = str.split('/')[2];​ // returns 'post1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expresion, something like:

```
new RegExp("/blog/(\S+)/").exec("/blog/post1/");
["/blog/post1/", "post1"]
```

**EDIT**

It's *RegExp*, not *Regex*, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Use the JavaScript `split` function. Much simpler solution.

```
var url = "/blog/post1/";
var splitUrl = url.split("/");

// assuming known URL structure so always same index
var post_slug = splitUrl[splitUrl.length -2];
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rsrmk/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/449Tn/)**

```
var str = "/blog/post1/";
arr = str.split('/');
var res = arr[arr.length-2];
alert(​res)​;
```

Comment: it's funny your answer looks almost identical to mine, posted 7 mins earlier ;)

Comment: We followed the same route :)

Comment: Yeah - just giving you a hard time :)